# Getting response from Castle Wcf facility async call

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, facilities

Say I have a call like so:

```
 _actService.BeginWcfCall(x => x.SaveAct(new SaveActRequest
                                                             {
                                                                 Act = act
                                                             }));
```

How do I get to the response of SaveAct? How can I set up a callback to fire when the operation completes?

I have tried:

```
    _actService.BeginWcfCall(x => x.GetAct(new GetActRequest
                                                            {
                                                                ActName =
                                                                    saveScheduleSlotRequest.ScheduleSlot.ActProxy.Name
                                                            }), (result) =>
                                                                    {
                                                                        var async = (GetActResponse)result.AsyncState;

                                                                    }, _actService);
```

But it complains about an ambiguous call?

Any pointers?

Comment: you have to specify the type of `result` explicitly I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Craig Neuwirt  answered this: http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/f440dbd05e60484f

I think you may be a little confused about the normal C# async pattern. 
It always involve a pair of Begin/End calls.

The WCF Facility support 2 callback models which is determined by the last 2 arguments of your BeginWcfCall

The 2 options are 
  1) Action>, state 
  2) AsyncCallback, state

Option 1 is the standard async pattern and would look like this

```
     _actService.BeginWcfCall(x => x.GetAct(new GetActRequest 
                                                            { 
                                                                ActName = 
                                                                    saveScheduleSlotRequest.ScheduleSlot.ActProxy.Name 
                                                            }), (IAsyncResult result) => 
                                                                    { 
                                                                        var response =  _actService.EndWcfCall<GetActResponse>(result); 
                                                                        // Do something with the response 
                                                                    });
```

As you can see, the first requires a reference to the _actService proxy to call end. The first is a convenience method which does not.

```
 _actService.BeginWcfCall(x => x.GetAct(new GetActRequest 
                                                            { 
                                                                ActName = 
                                                                    saveScheduleSlotRequest.ScheduleSlot.ActProxy.Name 
                                                            }), (IWcfAsyncCall<GetActResponse> result) => 
                                                                    { 
                                                                        var response =  result.End(); 
                                                                        // Do something with the response 
                                                                    });
```

The choice of which approach depends entirely on your preference of the c#standard async pattern.